# Is possible displays child views in horizontally of expandable ListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new Android developer. 
Generally Expandable ListView Group and Child View shows vertically.
But I want Group View show vertically but Child Views shows horizontally.
Child view may be 3 items. Is it possible?

Comment: provide us some image or reference of thing that you are talking about.

Comment: when click one group then 3 child view show horizontally, that means one row child with 3 items  33% space ok, group may be student and its child view may be name, roll, sex

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think that you can handle this by creating a horizontal scrollview to be your child item, and then in this view you can add whatever children you want.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/child1"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/child2"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/child3"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Let's say that you are having maximum three child items and you are having a list with the following architecture

```
Parent
   child1 child2
Parent
   child1
Parent 
   child1 child2 child3
```

Then you should have an adapter that have only one child item for each parent and you handle these items by
 - show two views for the first parent, one view for the second and all views for the third.

**Add some of your code so that i can show you the solution on your case.**